# Strength training for a mixed martial arts beginner

Tags: training, strength, beginner

I am starting MMA. Which excersises would be best to get my physical strength up to the levels of people doing MMA for years or experienced in MMA?

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/1756/347) has all the technical information you need, but recognize the following:

- You will not and cannot replicate the strength and conditioning of an experienced MMA fighter, since those athletes have a tremendous amount of **sport-specific** strength, conditioning, and skill that allows them to apply their general physical attributes efficiently and correctly to combat movements
- The best method for getting good at MMA is to train MMA or one of its component arts seriously
- The best way to improve conditioning for an activity is to do that activity, unless you are exceptionally efficient at the sport

Basically, as a novice to strength training, you should do the kind of [strength training any beginner should do](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/12406/1771):

- Squats
- Deadlifts
- Chin-ups or pull-ups
- Presses, like dips or overhead press
- Eventually, explosive movements like the Olympic lifts

It's quite straightforward. [There's no special MMA-style weightlifting](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/most_recent/11_myths_of_warrior_training); you just get strong and then get explosive and the whole time train your butt off in the sport. There are [other ways to get there](http://www.reddit.com/r/MMA/comments/qno4j/strength_training_and_mma/)--you could do lunges, Pendlay rows, and clean-and-presses instead, for instance--but the basic movements are constant.

Comment: The same is for most martial arts.
Also in judo, karate, capoera, etc you should be strong, agile, explosive etc.

In tai chi you may be not so strong.