# Can Martial Arts be learned alone?

Tags: self-training, wing-chun, tai-chi

The country I am living in only has 2 good teachers who taught kungfu and several for Martial arts. But I am more interested in Chinese lifestyle type martial arts like Tai Chi or Wing Chun. Can I learn any of the mentioned two just by myself, watching tutorial? Or I should wait until I can go to a country where I can find a mentor who taught these? Or is there a better way

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert, but I think this is the general answer to expect:

You can learn techniques, and understand concepts, just by watching videos or trying things out for yourself.

The issue is, if you practice with poor form (you're not throwing punches the correct way, or moving the right way, or using the right muscles), it is much harder to unlearn bad technique than it is to learn good technique from the beginning.

My advice to you, or to anyone who doesn't have martial arts gyms nearby, or has bad teachers, is to learn proper stretches, learn concepts, and learn ways of training your body, and work on fitness and flexibility first.

It is a risk to practice techniques using videos. It may turn out fine, but you may end up performing the techniques poorly, and without quality guidance to correct your mistakes, you could set yourself up to have to completely unlearn the technique.

EDIT: Also, it would help to know why you want to learn specifically Wing Chun and Tai Chi. If you just want to learn Tai Chi as an exercise tool, and not as a self-defense martial art, it should be fine to learn it alone.

My comment is more aimed at fighting arts, which are used for self-defense or competition.

Comment: not much I can add to this answer.  I just wanted to note that in these styles working with a partner is also important so you can feel the different kinds of energies and learn to respond appropriately. i.e. collapsing bridge techniques, jamming, parrying, trapping...

Comment: Could you move this answer to the [older question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/solo-martial-art-learning)?

Comment: My comment does not apply to that older post.