# Just for self defense

Tags: self-defense

Can I learn some self-defense on my own? I mean I don't really want to have professional martial art skill, but I want to be able to defend myself if facing someone attacking me. Can I learn that by my own? If so, is there any suggested resources to do so?

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate but I can see how it looks like one. OP, can you expend on whether it is a duplicate or if not, update it so it is clearly not one.

Comment: It's the same as learning a new language. Of course you can look up for every information, but if you do a technique wrong, noone will make you understand that you are doing it wrong. Noone that will lead and explain to you why a specific technique helps. Doing all the techniques correctly is important in very many ways! I would suggest you to do a test day at a martial arts school like Taekwondo. It's very funny, healthy sport, big knowledge and also teaches you so many important things you will love to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can learn self defence on your own. However, you *cannot learn to fight alone* because [of lots of reasons explained elsewhere.](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/solo-martial-art-learning)

Self defence is just stacking the deck in your favour. Martial arts are a useful addition, if only because they give you self confidence thus making you less of a target. There are many steps you can take to protect yourself that have nothing whatsoever to do with martial arts. Many (if not all) of these, you can learn by reading, although some will require some physical skill -- for example, gardening to plant roses below your windows.

A lot, if not all, of self defence features not getting in situations where you have to fight to keep safe. The latter should be avoided at all costs, as the risks far outweigh the benefits. I would rather lose my wallet (which contains nothing I cannot replace within 24 hours) than be stabbed. Better yet, not be there when someone pulls a knife…

[No nonsense self defense](https://www.nononsenseselfdefense.com/) is a good place to start and contains very useful information.