# Karate practise by thera band

Tags: karate, punching, power

Will punching by tying a [Thera band](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&bih=971&q=Thera+band&oq=Thera+band&gs_l=img.3...2031.2031.0.2211.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..1.0.0.sJbfbJhEpNI) on my hand or karate belt help me in improving my punching power? I am a karate student of seishinkai shito ryu style.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I have edited your question a little. Could you let us know why the answers to [Is there value in using weighted clothing in martial arts training?](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/2297/82) did not help you?

Comment: No it helped me

Comment: In this case, this is a duplicate and will likely be closed as such.

Comment: What is a duplicate

Comment: If the above answer helped you, then you need to edit this answer to make it different. As it stands, it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, no it won't.

A punch is a delivery of kinetic force; a resistance band will simply help you burn more calories and maybe increase your muscle tone a little.

Using a resistance band will tend to work your hand grip, forearms, triceps and anterior deltoid muscles. Punching with weights will do the same however it will also indirectly stress your latissimus dorsi muscles (as they compensate to help you keep balance), you will also tend to adjust the motion so that the medial deltoid muscles also have some assistance.

A resistance band will possibly alter your punch technique in a suboptimal way - the line of resistance will never perfectly line up with the trajectory your punch should take and your muscles will consequently compensate and work in a way that is not an optimal motion for punching, especially once you start to tire. If you really want to apply resistance to your punching movements then do them standing submersed in water.

A resistance band will also not help you build your focus. Focus is that moment when you achieve a combination of maximum tension and maximum kinetic energy and it is a critical element of your punch - if you lack it then the punch is little more than a bludgeon or a shove with a closed fist.

Comment: Slugster i am a student of karate and my style is shito ryu, in my style we don't harm our oponents and we only do touch back punches so can u tell me which is the main part of our punch and how can we improve our punches because i am fan of karate

Comment: That is a whole new question and way too involved to discuss in comments. Disregarding any philosophical differences we may have about "harming our opponents" and definitions of a "touch back punch", focus is still the key part of the punch. You can deliver different amounts of kinetic energy - "focus" is the culmination of energy and tension (and a resistance band is not going to help train focus).

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe it will help with punching power as power relies on mass and speed.

1. Mass relies on coordination of the whole body and there is a lot more to be gained practising better coordination.
2. Speed relies on coordintaion as well as reducing resistance which is attained by limiting the use of antagonistic muscles. This device will engage them.

What this sort of device can help with is continuous pull power which is better suited to grappling. For example a snap down on a head or arm comes to mind.

Comment: I have used these sorts of bands. Mainly in wrestling by wrapping it around a fence and using it for fast pull downs many times over. I played with it in striking and found the anatomical dynamics did not work at all for me.

Comment: Thank you. The "believe" made me think that you were guessing...

Comment: No problem. I like to be scientific & what works for me is not a large sample  set hence belief. I have seen these types of bands help others in grappling especially when loaded with 2 or 3 to make them really hard to snap down.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried what you suggest, but it sounds awkward. It also seems to me that it might impede proper form in punch delivery.  If you want stronger punches increase the strength of your whole body, focus on using proper form in practice, and do bag work with a partner. Something like a resistance band tied to your belt is going to offer resistance in strange way, and may actually end up doing more harm than good.

If you want some training advice on an exercise that is proven to produce results in your punching speed and strength, start doing Clap Pushups (of course YMMV).

Comment: What do u mean by bag work with a partner

Comment: @user26453 I mean heavy bag workouts with a partner holding the bag. A partner can stabilize the bag so you can really drive your punches into it without worrying about it swinging out of range (which is really helpful if you are doing high intensity interval training with the bag). It might not seem like it, but there is a huge difference between hitting a free hanging heavy bag and hitting one held by a partner.

Comment: Thanx but i am not having any bag but i am having a kicking pad will it help

Comment: @user26453 It might help some, but not in the way a heavy bag does. A kicking pad doesn't have the mass or resistance of a heavy bag, nor will it protect your training partner as effectively in a high intensity punching routine.

Comment: Zen i am not having a heavy punching bag but i have thick pillows in my home can they help me in improving my punch power

Comment: @user26453 I honestly can't answer your question without knowing what the pillows you are talking about are like, but they almost certainly are going to be more like a kick pad than a heavy bag. While I think a heavy bag is an invaluable training tool, there are other ways to improve your punching power.  Like I mentioned in my original answer, Clap Pushups (and similar plyometric exercises) can increase speed, power, and reaction time. Also, regularly practicing on using proper posture, alignment, and delivery for your punches means the difference between an optimal impact and a wasted effort